# Flutter How to convert List into and from JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

There are two Functions that I use to convert two String variables into JSON and from JSON.

```
String toJson() {
  Map<String,dynamic> map = {'name': name,'count':checkListCount,'description':description,};
  return jsonEncode(map)
}

fromJson(String context){
  Map<String,dynamic> map = jsonDecode(contents)
  name = map['name'];
  description = map['description'];
  return '0';
}
```

How i can use this to functions to covert List?
There is my list

```
List<CheckListPoint> checkListPoints = [];

CheckListPoint{
  bool correctly = false;
  bool passed = false;
  String requirement = '';
}
```

variables that I have in CheckListPoint will change by the user later in the app.

Comment: Follow this tutorial about serialization in flutter: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 1):

i am not exactly getting which key will give you the list of data from your question,
but suppose you have a response in with "data" key is giving you list of items,
then you can add from JSON with ->

```
    data : List<User>.from(json["data"].map((x) => User.fromJson(x))),
```

and to convert it to JSON you need

```
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
```

i hope this is what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

I did a very similiar thing when fetching messages from firebase. It's the same as parsing from JSON since both values are *dynamic*.

Here I convert a *DataSnapshot* to a *List*

```dart
Future<List<Message>> getMessages(DataSnapshot snapshot) async {
    List<Message> msgs = List.empty(growable: true);
    if(snapshot.value != null) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> messages = snapshot.value;
      messages.forEach((key, value) {
        msgs.add(Message.fromFirebase(value));
      });
    }
    return msgs;
 }
```

And here is the *Message* class:

```dart
class Message {
  String message;
  String senderId;
  int time;

  Message.fromFirebase(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) :
      message = json["message"],
      senderId = json["senderId"],
      time = json["time"];
}
```